# How to config proxy in Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, proxy

All:

I am new to virtualbox. I install virtualbox on a WIndow7x64 box(`IP: 45.37.2.38, Mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway:45.37.2.1`) which is behind office's proxy, inside virtualbox, I install Ubuntu 14.04 server. During the installation, I set proxy credential, and use other default setting except using bridge mode connection in virtualbox(`IP: 45.37.2.42, Mask: 255.255.255.0`).

Right now, I run apache inside ubuntu and I can visit from windows. And in ubuntu, I can use sudo apt-get update, but can NOT ping www.google.com(which says Destination Host Unreachable.)

My route table is like:

```
default     45.37.2.1  0.0.0.0         UG
45.37.2.0   *          255.255.255.0   U
```

My questions are:

> 1. Should I set proxy in somewhere? (I already set it once during installation)
> 2. Is this route wrong to send request out? Why I can not ping www.google.com?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether you are able to ping your proxy server using Ubuntu in your virtual box. the command for this is :

`ping <address_of_the_proxy_server>`

If you are able to ping the proxy-server, now you can check whether your credentials are correctly set or not.Open the terminal and run `env`.

A lot of information will appear on the screen. Check for `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. If they are not correctly set you can set them using a Graphical tool named `ubproxy` .You can download a python it to set proxy authentication. Here is the [link](http://code.google.com/p/ubproxy/downloads/detail?name=ubproxy) to it.

Or else you can set proxy authentication using the following steps:

Go to `/etc/apt`. Create the file `apt.conf` if you don't have it there. Write the following lines there.

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
```

Save it. You are done.
If the problem persists please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool to simplify the entire task.

## You can download it from [this link.](https://github.com/himanshushekharb16/ProxyMan/releases)

**Also, you can have a look at the code if you are more interested to know the backend functioning.** 
Download the zip file,extract them, go to the location of extracted files in terminal and following commands would help you:
* bash main.sh : *to set and unset proxy.*

* bash proxy_check.sh : *to check your current proxy settings.*